# Filtering Sentinel 1 Imagery

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm working with Sentinel 1 radar imagery. For some images in the collection in parentheses next to the angle band the is a percentage (see image)

[image]

When I do some further steps in my analysis these images return a masked pixel and I therefore need to select a different image. What does this percentage refer too? And is there a way to filter images where this occurs so I can remove them from the ImageCollection I couldn't find an obvious image property?

Answer (score 2):

The mask can be partial — any value between 0 (masked/absent) and 1 (unmasked/present). Such pixels usually appear at the edge of an image. 54% in the inspector means the mask value is 0.54 (rounded) at that point.

You could use `image.updateMask(image.mask().eq(1))` to change all mask values that are not 1 to be exactly 0, thus discarding those pixels, if that is useful in your application.